# Getting the legend label for a line in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given that I have a line object in matplotlib, how do I get what the legend label will be for that line?

The `get_label()` method of the Artist class only works if the legend did not change or create the label (using `plt.legend()` or similar).

Getting the *handler* associated with a line is possible using `Legend.get_legend_handler()`, but that isn't associated with any text.  `Legend.get_lines()` gives a list of line objects... but they aren't the same objects that are plotted.

An example of how `get_label()` doesn't work:

```
x = [0,1]
y = [1,1]
line, = plt.plot(x,y)
plt.legend(("hello",))
plt.plot()

line.get_label() # returns '_line0'
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Unclear: `get_label()` will give you the label of the line. This will be the label used in the legend. Why is this not what you're looking for? Remember it always helps to produce a [mcve] of the issue - in this case create some code and show what it produces. Clearly state what the code should produce instead.

Comment: I edited the post.  `get_label()` only returns the label of the line if the line was created with a label.  Creating a legend label using a `legend()` call doesn't modify the line to add a label, and thus doesn't  work.

Comment: But you create the label yourself, so you already know it's `"hello"`?!

Comment: Yes, because you asked for a contrived example.  I'm working on fixing a bug in matplotlib2tikz, which requires recreating the plot from a figure object.  I don't have access to the code that creates the plot.

Comment: ok, but you do have access to the legend?

Comment: You can get the legend using `line.axes.get_legend()`

Answer (score 9):

There is no general way of knowing if a legend contains a label for a given artist. The artist can have a custom label or not and this does not neccesarily need to coincide with the label used in the legend.

A solution will therefore **always** depend on assumptions.

**A.** If we assume that the artists are given a label and that this label is the one shown in the legend, the solution is easy:

```
line.get_label()
```

**B.** If we assume that the order by which the lines are created is the same as they appear in the legend and that no other artists are put in between, we could do

```
def get_label_for_line(line):
    leg = line.axes.get_legend()
    ind = line.axes.get_lines().index(line)
    return leg.texts[ind].get_text()
```

**C.** If we assume that the legend has been created directly from the artists (and not other proxy artists), we can compare the label, like

```
def get_label_for_line(line):
    leg = line.axes.get_legend()
    for h, t in zip(leg.legendHandles, leg.texts):
        if h.get_label() == line.get_label():
            return t.get_text()
```

For other solutions, one would need to know more about how exactly the figure, its artists and the legend are created.